# Could someone check my code and help me out with a problem? Error = "list index out of range"

Tags: python

```
import random
```

> #variable will count how many letters are in the word the computer chooses
> count = 0

```
user = input("Guess letter: ")
word = random.choice(["LONDON", "RESPECT", "ABSOLUTE"])
```

> #This seperates each letter and makes a list
> letters = list(word)

> #Loop counts letters in the word and updates the variable

```
for i in range(0, len(word)):  
        if(word[i] != ' '):  
           count = count + 1;
```

> #This checks if any of the letter that the user guessed is in the list letters

```
if user == letters[0] or user == letters[1] or user == letters[2] or user == letters[3] or user == letters[4] or user == letters[5] or user == letters[6] or user == letters[7]:
    print("well done")
else:
    print("nope")

print(letters)
print(" _ " * count)
```

Comment: BTW I am trying to make a hang man game

Comment: what is `letters`

Comment: Just an FYI, it looks like your huge `if user == letters[0] or user == letters[1] ...` line could be replaced with `if user in letters`. But since you have not defined `letters` that's only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the error's coming from your long `if .. or` statement. By replacing it you'll not only shorten your code, but also make it easier to debug:

```py
import random

# computer selects secret word
word = random.choice(["LONDON", "RESPECT", "ABSOLUTE"])

#This seperates each letter and makes a list
letters = list(word) # <-- not actually needed!

#variable will count how many letters are in the word the computer chooses
count = len(letters)

# accept user input & convert to upper case
user = input("Guess letter: ").upper() 

#This checks if any of the letter that the user guessed is in the list letters
if user in letters:
    print("well done")
else:
    print("nope")

print(letters)
print(" _ " * count)
```

---

Keep working on your own approach, but if you get stuck, here's how I'd approach the guessing part of the game. You'd still need to figure out how you want to track incorrect guesses and game over:

```py
import random

# computer selects secret word
letters = random.choice(["LONDON", "RESPECT", "ABSOLUTE"])

print(f'Guess the {len(letters)} letter word!')

user_guesses = []
# Keep going until user is correct
while True:
    # accept user input & convert to upper case
    user = input('\nGuess letter: ').upper()
    user_guesses.append(user)

    # if user's guess is in the word, display it, otherwise display _
    progress = []
    for letter in letters:
        if letter in user_guesses:
            progress.append(letter)
        else:
            progress.append('_')

    print(''.join(progress))
    if progress == letters:
        print('You win')
        break
```